# One bigger partition or few smaller but more distributed partitions for Range Queries in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

We have a table that stores our data partitioned by files. One file is 200MB to 8GB in json - but theres a lot of overhead obviously. Compacting the raw data will lower this drastically. I ingested about 35 GB of json data and only one node got slightly more than 800 MB data. This is possibly due to "write hotspots" -- but we only write once and read only. We do not update data. Currently, we have one partition per file.

By using secondary indexes, we search for partitions in the database that contain a specific geolocation (= first query) and then take the result of this query to range query a time range of the found partitions (= second query). **This might even be the whole file if needed but in 95% of the queries only chunks of a partition are queried.**

We have a replication factor of 2 on a 6 node cluster. Data is fairly even distributed, every node owns 31,9% to 35,7% (effective) data according to `nodetool status *tablename*`.

Good read performance is key for us.

My questions:

1. How big is too big for a partition in terms of volume or row size? Is there a rule of thumb for this?
2. For Range Query performance: Is it better to split up our "big" partitions to have more smaller partitions? We built our schema with "big" partitions because we thought that when we do range queries on a partition, it would be good to have it all on one node so data can be fetched easily. Note that the data is also available on one replica due to RF 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. C* supports very huge rows, but it doesn't mean it is a good idea to go to that level. The *right* limit depends on specific use cases, but a good ballpark value could be between 10k and 50k. Of course, everything is a compromise, so if you have "huge" (in terms of bytes) rows then heavily limit the numbers of rows in each partition. If you have "small" (in terms of bytes) rows them you can relax that limit a bit. This is because **one** partition means **one** node only due to your **RF=1**, so all your query for a specific partition will hit only one node.
2. Range queries should ideally go to one partition only. A range query means a sequential scan on your partition on the node getting the query. However, you will limit yourself to the *throughput* of that node. If you split your range queries between more nodes (that is you change the way you partition your data by adding something like a *bucket*) you need to get data from different nodes as well performing *parallel* queries, directly increasing the total throughput. Of course you'd lose the order of your records within different buckets, so if the order in your partition matters, then that could not be feasible.

Comment: Sorry, I misused the word replication factor. We actually have RF 2 (`CREATE KEYSPACE whatever WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dc1': '2'}  AND durable_writes = true;`). I edited the question accordingly. Will reads be redirected to the replica if the "main" node is under pressure already?

Comment: RF=2 just means that 2 (read) queries on the same partition could hit 2 different nodes.If that happens depends on your C* driver.However, this won't make the throughput of **one** query any better.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I think this perfectly suits our use case though. Our first query (see above) will usually return several files (= partitions) that contain the searched field. Because these are (ideally) located on different nodes, we will hit several nodes in the follow-up query. A driver that is aware of the replication could re-route the query to the replica instead when the other node got a query to perform already. Do you know whether the datastax C* driver is "replica aware"?

Comment: This is what you're looking for: [DataStax](https://datastax.github.io/java-driver/manual/load_balancing/)